# Reload method of already existing object on console in Python

Tags: python, console, reload

In the Python console (Eclipse, Pydev) I execute some data loading. Afterwards I change some source code of a method of the object and would like to include the new functionality in the data objects. The data loading is quite slow so I do not want to restart the whole script.

Is there a magic way to update the object methods with the new implementation that I edited in the source code?

[How to reload the code of a method of class object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670586/how-to-reload-the-code-of-a-method-of-class-object-in-python) says I cannot do this in a standard way.

So can you think of some way to simulate that functionality? Maybe reload the class definition and then recreate all data objects by examining their `__dict__` or similar? Ideally this would be as automatic and comfortable as possible. What do I need to take into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Python can't replace existing instances of objects out of the box. However,  `IPython` implements this functionality as extension. You could use IPython as Python console or just re-implement this feature for your development environment.

See [Autoreload of modules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython), [and ipython docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html).

Comment: I see :) However, it would not reload class of objects that are already in memory?

Comment: It actually does reload classes which are already in memory. Try example of ipython autoreload using from previously mentioned SO question. For me it works also with with classes and objects.